# SWIG C++ to python with multiple extensions in module on Ubuntu (vs MacOS)

Tags: python, c++, swig, ubuntu-20.04, macos-monterey

I am trying to run C++ code, wrapped with SWIG into Python 3.8 modules on a remote computing cluster (where I don't have root access). I was writing the code on my own computer (MacOS Monterey) while the cluster runs Ubuntu20.04. The Code makes use of libraries [quadedge](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/2001/pub/src/a2/quadedge.html), [nlopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [gsl](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). Using the latter two I perform an optimisation with nlopt and integration with gsl every step however this only works on my own Mac, on the Ubuntu cluster there's some undefined behaviour during runtime, i.e. my rate of change when integrating is zero at around 50% of the integration steps (On the Mac everything works flawlessly).
To install my code as python modules, I use a setup.py. The procedure and module structure I use is currently the following:

- install quadedge
- install polygeo (own module that depends on quadedge)
- install plantdevelopment (own module that depends on polygeo)

Both polygeo and plantdevelopment contain two extensions in one module. My setup.py for polygeo on my Mac looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py
import os
import glob

class build_py(_build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        return super().run()

polygeoDir = 'polygeo/'
surfnloptDir = 'polygeo/surfnlopt/'
includeDir = 'polygeo/include/'
srcDir = 'polygeo/src/'

headerFiles = glob.glob(includeDir + '*.hpp')
srcFiles = glob.glob(srcDir + '*.cpp')
srcFiles.append(polygeoDir + 'polygeo.i')

surfnloptHeaderFiles = glob.glob(surfnloptDir + 'include/*.hpp')
surfnloptSrcFiles = glob.glob(surfnloptDir + 'src/*.cpp')
surfnloptSrcFiles.append(surfnloptDir + 'surfnlopt.i')

allHeaders = []
allHeaders += headerFiles
allHeaders += surfnloptHeaderFiles

polygeoExt = Extension('_polygeo',
                       sources=srcFiles,
                       include_dirs=[includeDir],
                       library_dirs=[],
                       libraries=[],
                       swig_opts=['-c++'],
                       extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],)

surfnloptExt = Extension('surfnlopt._surfnlopt',
                         sources=surfnloptSrcFiles,
                         include_dirs=[includeDir,
                                       surfnloptDir + '/include'],
                         library_dirs=[],
                         libraries=['m', 'nlopt'],
                         swig_opts=['-c++'],
                         extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],)

setup(name='polygeo',
      version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages(),
      ext_package='polygeo',
      ext_modules=[polygeoExt,
                   surfnloptExt],
      install_requires=['quadedge'],
      headers=allHeaders,
      cmdclass = {'build_py' : build_py},
      )
```

Interestingly, it seems not to be necessary on my Mac to add extra paths or anything, but on the remote it requires me to edit the .bash_profile in order to set the necessary includepaths etc..
On top of that on Ubuntu it is required though to also add to each of the extensions the `extra_link_args=['/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/quadedge/_quadedge.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'],`that point to the cpython.so that I already generated with the setup.py for quadedge.

Also I need to add the source files of the polygeo extension to the source files of surfnlopt, i.e. `sources=srcFiles+surfnloptSrcFiles,` otherwise it throws a "symbols not found" error when importing the modules in python, because surfnlopt depends on the source files of polygeo (same if I don't include the .so as it also needs functions from quadedge).

For installing plantdevelopment my script looks almost the same, however there I have to include the polygeo.so instead of quadedge.so and have to add `swig_opts=['-c++','-I'+polygeoIncDir]`that points to the directory where the header files from the polygeo setup end up.

First thing I was wondering if it causes problems to have the extensions depend on the previously installed ones as then plantdevelopment also depends on polygeo and its extensions.
Could adding the source files to the extensions again, have an impact due to ambiguity/duplication when running the code? Could this be a memory leak?
So far I tried the following:

- try to have as little includes/sources as possible to avoid overdefinition in the setup.py
- try to install python locally on the Ubuntu remote with hombrew and pyenv with all software the same version as on the Mac (as well as the compiler)
- tried out python 3.10 as there apparently used to be a memory leak issue at some point
- tried to install everything on Mac without root privileges (still works flawlessly)
- tried to put ALL files into one single module (which doesn't work due to abstract classes and the C++ code structure)
- tested that the C++ code without python is working properly to make sure it's not about the C libraries (unfortunately I need the python API for the project and it's not my choice)
- Using the guppy memory profiler, actually some of the runs (~50%) work out properly, already when I just import it and print the heap status, however there seems to be a lot of randomness...

In my program I use guppy the following way:

```
heap = hpy()

print("Heap Status At Starting : ")
heap_status1 = heap.heap()
print("Heap Size : ", heap_status1.size, " bytes\n")
print(heap_status1)


heap.setref()

print("\nHeap Status After Setting Reference Point : ")
heap_status2 = heap.heap()
print("Heap Size : ", heap_status2.size, " bytes\n")
print(heap_status2)
```

I can't really think of a reason why just importing and printing the heap info should change anything of the outcome of my optimization/integration?

Could this be an issue with the different OS?

Or maybe the code structure it problematic with python, building everything on top of each other/having dependencies between extensions in a single module?

I'd be happy for any kind of help and will of course provide any further necessary info.

Comment: If you haven't solved it. Try using the `ldd` tool on your shared objects to what the dependencies are. Try building quadedge and ensure that you are using the version that you build yourself.

Comment: @JensMunk On the Mac polygeo depends on nothing except libc++ and libsystem.B.dylib, on the cluster it is linux-vdso.so.1, libstdc++.so.6, libm.so.6, libgcc_s.so.1, libpthread.so.0, libc.so.6 and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

On the cluster on importing polygeo to python it says `ImportError: undefined symbol: _ZN4Cell14makeVertexEdgeEP6VertexP4FaceS3_`. This is a quadedge function.

This is also what I see from `nm`on the polygeo cpython.so, it's marked as "U". The same is true locally on the Mac, however there it does not complain about undefined symbols

Comment: Then you need to find the shared object containing the missing symbol and link against it. It may be linked statically in your setup on your Mac, since there you have no undefined symbols

Comment: @JensMunk I did that and the installation process and module loading work if I add as extra_link_args the shared object that contains the symbols. One thing is though that the "subextensions", e.g. surfnlopt require either the polygeo.so (which doesn't exist already at the point where it would be required) or if I include the source files of polygeo. I'm not sure this is the "right" way of doing that though, as code results are wrong (integration fails unlike on my Mac). Is there maybe a different approach? I don't think on my Mac I have any static linking, but maybe I can try this on Ubuntu.

Comment: The right way is to ensure the right linkage. The reason why it works on your mac could be due to LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to a folder containing `polygeo.so`. If you include the code, it will also work, since everything is dynamically loaded (DON'T DO THAT)